# How to send an email in python using smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

My code:

```
import smtplib

try:
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    print("Connection successful")
except:
    print("Connection failed")

content = str(input("Your message: "))

senderLogin = str(input('Your full email (currently only GMail): '))
senderPass = str(input('Your password(data is not stored): '))

receiverAcc = str(input('Who would you like to send it to: '))

mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.ehlo

mail.login(senderLogin, senderPass)
try:
    mail.sendmail(senderLogin, receiverAcc, content)
    print ("Email sent")

except:
    print('error')

mail.close()
```

I cannot get it to work. All that happens is that the shell pops up and it is a blank screen. Nothing else. If anyone can clarify and/or help, that would be great. Also, I have already enabled the lower-security apps in my google account.

**UPDATE**

I played around with the ports and found out that port 25 for smtp.gmail.com works.

Comment: What was your output?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are being blocked by Google's SMTP server. You should try a different SMTP server and adjust usage of `mail.starttls()` as needed. Otherwise, your code should work.